# python setup.py build ignoring some files

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

I have the following structure for my Python package:

```
$ tree -d | grep -v "__pycache__"
.
├── src
│   ├── poliastro
│   │   ├── iod
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   └── twobody
│   │       └── tests
├── setup.py
└── MANIFEST.in

47 directories
```

Buf after performing `python setup.py build`, the innermost `test` directory is not getting copied:

```
$ tree -d | grep -v "__pycache__"
.
├── build
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── poliastro
│   │       ├── iod
│   │       ├── tests
│   │       └── twobody
```

On the contrary, `python setup.py sdist` works correctly.

So far I've used the `MANIFEST.in` rules to include or exclude certain files, patterns and directories from the sdist. Is there a way to control what goes to the `build` directory? Why some tests are getting there and some others aren't?

Reference to original issue and source code: https://github.com/poliastro/poliastro/issues/129

Comment: Can you share the `MANIFEST.in` content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setup()` is missing `include_package_data=True`. See this PR I have made https://github.com/poliastro/poliastro/pull/139

Discussion: Without this, non-python package files (such as the test py files you list that are not "in a package") are not included by default, even though they are technically part of an otherwise included Python package directory tree.
/HTH

Comment: Wow, pull request included :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `__init__.py` files inside the included folders specified in `MANIFEST.in`.

Comment: The problem is that they are test folders so not intended to be imported.

Comment: Ok. In the past I found out that after install, the pip tool removed all the folders that not were specified as a module (with a \_\_init\_\_.py inside).